# How to inject custom url path for page ?

Tags: pages, urls, page-template, site-url, paths

Is it possible to make custom URL path for pages ? 
The current page url is http://localhost.dev/insight which I need to show like http://localhost.dev/city/local/insight are any option in wordpress to customise the url ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use this plugin to generate this kind of permalink https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to register a new post type for this. In custom post types you can easily control the url structure. Use the [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function for this.

In this function you can add a `rewrite` variable. This variable controls the slug / url structure. Check out this example:

```
function insight_init() {
  register_post_type( 'insight', array(
      'labels'            => array(),
      'public'            => true,
      'hierarchical'      => false,
      'show_ui'           => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
      'has_archive'       => false,
      'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'city/local')),
      'query_var'         => true,
      'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-analytics',
  ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'insight_init' );
```

Answer (score 1):

For a page, you need to create a parent page(s) with the slug you want to put in between. Then you may choose these pages as a parent to the last slug page (insight page in your case). It will insert the needed slugs into your URL.

So you need to create /city page, then /local page and make /local child to /city page parent. then make /insight page child to /local parent.

Then you may change parent pages visibility to i.e. drafts or private. URL will be preserved.

Comment: This solves a more extended definition of the OP request. In my case, I'm looking to create the path : site.tld/country/state/county/city/neighborhood. The locality types here arent important, a location might be missing a county so the path will be /country/state/city/... This answer by @iggy addresses this challenge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The custom post type method mentioned is likely the superior one, but if you are not comfortable with registering a post type or using that code in a plugin of your own, there is a plugin that the WordPress codex recommends for this: [WP Category Permalink](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/).

This is part of the larger entry regarding using [permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/).